# How do I fix my footer and the bottom of this page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix a table and make it look better (I describe the issue better in the screen shot below).

this is a screen shot of what's going on and what I would like to happen:

[image]

What do I change in my style sheet?

the css file is located at [rankingclimber.com/css/style.css](http://rankingclimber.com/css/style.css) (the footer part is clearly marked) and the signup part is clearly marked

The sign up page is located at [www.rankingclimber.com/signup.php](http://www.rankingclimber.com/signup.php)

here's the code for the footer file: [rankingclimber.com/footer.php](http://rankingclimber.com/footer.php) and the footer is called on the main page: [rankingclimber.com/signup.php](http://rankingclimber.com/signup.php)

Comment: here is verbose report of what is going on with your page: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rankingclimber.com%2Fsignup.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the placement of the line, move `<div class="form_bt"></div>` to just after the closing tag of `<div class="form_tp">`.

To fix the "Create Account" button not being inside the form, from `<div class="chkp3">`, remove `float: left` and `margin-bottom: 20px`. Then, to `<a class="btn1">`, add `margin-top: 20px`.

To fix the footer, move `<div id="footer">` to just after the closing tag for `<div id="wrapper">`.

Tested in Firefox only, with Firebug.

---

*Another answer pointed out you have missing close tags. In that case, my answer might not be very useful as the problems could have been caused purely by those missing tags.*

Fix the missing close tags, and then see what your page is like before following any of the steps I posted.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. Thirtydot that was awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, add `margin:0; !important` to the `.form_bt` style. Safari Web Inspector shows it currently has a `margin-right` of -60px. And in your HTML, put the `div.form_bt` outside of the `<form>` element, it's currently inside it.

Comment: thanks Anriëtte! I made sure my div.form_bt was outside the form element.

Answer (score 0):

try these fixes, I can't validate since I don't have all of your files, but you are missing closing tags for:

1. Missing `</li>` after the code: `<li><a href="what-is-ranking-climber.php">What is Ranking Climber?</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;`
2. Missing `</div>` before the code: `</form>`

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
clear: both;

<div id="container">

      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>          

</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS for these DIV's

```
#container{
  width:950px;
  min-height:500px;  // This will helps you to stick to footer to bottom about 500px below
}
.left{ width: 50%;}
.right { width:50%;}

.footer{
  widht: 950px;
  clear: both; // This will helps you to avoid footer to overlap. Use this when Some      elements is overlapping 
}
```